# C++ force override

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, virtual

I have some class, like

```
class object {
public:
virtual std::string name() const; 
};
```

It provides some interface, and I want all derivated to override method `name`. 
Problem is, it is not overriden, nothing breaks at compile time, but I get problems in run-time.
Is it any way to enforce method overriding?
EDIT: I want to enforce overriding in all derivates, not just direct descedants!

Comment: I question that this would build correctly. You should be getting linker errors.

Comment: Yes, I did not printed definition. Why? It's all about interfaces.

Comment: Have you considered using RTTI instead?

Comment: RTTI type_info::name is compiler-specific. I need to have fixed string.

Comment: Maybe comment about downvote?

Comment: @KerrekSB: already std::string and not being defined inlnie as constexpr should error out

Comment: I really feel XY problem here...

Comment: @illusionoflife: There is no way to enforce this for all derived classes which does not require you to add code for each derived class, except documentation and human brain.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9661580/819272 for an attempt to force all derived classes to override

Comment: I dont understand how that solution would work, the ctor there would accept any function with the same signature, it wont have to override `foo()` specificaly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check whether a member is defined in a base class by checking its pointer-to-member type:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(&U::name), std::string (U::*)()>::value,
              "name must be defined directly in U");
```

This does mean that at compile time you must have access to all the descendant types that you're interested in.

Comment: Well, it requires to add code into descendants, not into object. But it will still help. Thank!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, make it a *pure* virtual:

```
constexpr virtual std::string name() = 0;
```

Comment: And so what? It enforce overriding in first derivate, not all subsequent!

Comment: @illusionoflife you didn't specify that requirement in your question.

Comment: `all derivated`. Well, probably it is not obvilous. Will edit.