# Require override of parent virtual function

Tags: c++

I'm working on a serialization system, and all my serializable classes implement

```
virtual void serialize(Buffer buffer);
```

When a pointer is going to be serialized, I need to call the serialize() function of the class itself, and not that of any of its parents, even if the pointer is a parent type, and I've been running into a lot of bugs because I don't notice that a child class doesn't even have serialize() at all so the parent serialize() class is just being called

ie

```
class A
{
    virtual void serialize();
}

class B:public A
{
    virtual void serialize();
}

class C:public B
{
    virtual void serialize();
}

void doSerialization(A *a)
{
    a->serialize();
}


C *c=new C();
doSerialization(c);
```

right now, if C didn't have a serialize function, B::serialize() would be silently called.  I'd prefer an error message, or anything else that will at least point it out to me.  Is there any keyword in C++ (even '11) that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *easy* way of doing so in C++.

There *is* a hack though, explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9661580/1225541), using virtual inheritance and forcing your classes to register which `serialize` method they are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use pure virtual function in parent:

```
virtual void serialize(Buffer buffer) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

At compile time you can only do that by making the function a pure virtual function in classes that are not final:

```
class A
{
    virtual void serialize() = 0;
}

class B:public A
{
    virtual void serialize() = 0;
}

class C final:public B
{
    virtual void serialize();
}
```

Of course that means that all concrete classes in your design need to be `final`. If you must inherit from concrete classes, you can't enforce this at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

> right now, if C didn't have a serialize function B::serialize() would be silently called.

No, you'll get linker error. As I see, that's what you want.

Comment: I think what he means is that if C didn't declare one then B's would be called.  That makes his statement make sense, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One variant to solve this is is to not inherit several layers, so instead of `class C: public B`, you use `class C: public A`. Of course, that's not necessarily a suggestion for all scenarios.

At some point sooner or later, you do have to leave things in the hand of the programmer.

There may be some ways to check this as well, - maybe create a temporary pointer to `B` and check if `typeid(*this) == typeid(temp)` or some such?