# Turning a non-pure virtual function into pure in a subclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual

So, I have this polymorphic hierarchy:

```
ClassA
Is not abstract, no pure virtual functions, but a few virtual functions

ClassB:public ClassA
Defines an extended interface for a certain type of subclass; 
 is abstract with pure virtual functions

ClassC:public ClassB
Usable class, no more subclassing
```

Here's the deal, I will have objects of `ClassA` and `ClassC` thrown together into containers and iterated through. To perform this iteration, a non-pure virtual function is present in `ClassA` but is empty with just `{}`; that is, it is empty, made available only if the iteration encounters a `ClassC` in which case it is invoked, otherwise it does nothing. I can't have it be pure otherwise I cannot have objects of `ClassA`.

But to ensure that `ClassC` does in fact implement that function, forcing the user of that class to do so, I make this function pure virtual in `ClassB`.

Is this acceptable? Nothing will "break" if I take a non-pure virtual function, make it pure, then make it non-pure again in `ClassC` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're fine if implemented as you present in your explanation. Without going into entire sections on abstract base classes and virtual functions, the standard dictates:

> **C++ § 10.4p2**
>
> An abstract class is a class that can be used only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it. A class is abstract if it has at least one pure virtual function. [ Note: Such a function might be inherited: see below. — end note ] A virtual function is specified pure by using a pure-specifier (9.2) in the function declaration in the class definition. A pure virtual function need be defined only if called with, or as if with (12.4), the qualified-id syntax (5.1)

The "below" referenced above leads to this note:

> **C++11 § 10.4p5**
>
> [*Note:* An abstract class can be derived from a class that is not abstract, and a pure virtual function may override a virtual function which is not pure. - *end note*]

Comment: This functionality is only in C++11? That's interesting.

Comment: @Fellowshee It is the standard I have handy, and would not feel correct in saying it was fine for *all* of standards-based-C++ unless I had them all at my finger tips. I would think it *likely* to have been supported all along, however.

Answer (score 1):

> a non-pure virtual function is present in `ClassA` but not implemented;

That results in **linker error**. When creating an objects of `ClassA` or its subclasses, all `virtual` methods must be implemented. Only for pure `virtual` methods the body of the method is optional.

> But to ensure that `ClassC` does in fact implement that function,
>   forcing the user of that class to do so, I make this function pure
>   `virtual` in `ClassB`.

Yes, this way is correct. But, you should also evaluate that, is it worth having a new class just to make sure that few methods are implemented or not?
For C++11, you can think of making smart use of `override` identifier as well.

Also, you should not worry about the internal details of `vtable`, as they are implementation defined.

Comment: I have updated my question with the correct terminology. I didn't mean "not implemented" i meant "empty implementation"

Comment: @Fellowshee, Still the remaining part should answer your question. Also you can refer [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477581/force-all-classes-to-implement-override-a-pure-virtual-method-in-multi-level), where I discuss about similar problem.