# How can I override a purely virtual method, yet still force child classes to implement the same method?

Tags: c++

I have an abstract base class with one purely virtual method:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
};
```

Is there any way I could create a class that inherits from `Base`, overrides the `update` method, but still forces its children to implement an `update` method? Like this:

```
class Base2 : public Base
{
public:
    void update() override
    {
        if(bSomeCondition)
        {
            update(); //Calls child's update method
        }
    }
    virtual void update() = 0; // Obviously not like this
};
```

I know I could create two new purely virtual methods with slightly different names in `Base2`, and just override those in child classes, but I would really like to keep these method names if that would be possible.

I'm guessing this isn't possible?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477581/force-all-classes-to-implement-override-a-pure-virtual-method-in-multi-level

Comment: So, it is possible, but it's unclear what you hope to achieve. When would the intermediate function be called, and why?

Comment: I suspect you might be better off making a Base0 that both Base and Base2 are child classes that override the function of Base0

Comment: The usual approach is to derive classes directly from `Base`, not from `Base2`.   In other words, don't derive from concrete (instantiable) classes.   C++11 and later, that can be enforced by tagging `Base2`  as `final`.

Comment: *"`// Obviously not like this`"* -- well, obviously the line stating "obviously" is the obvious way to do it. It's the inline definition above the "obviously" line that is obviously the problem. :) *Have I mentioned recently that "obviously" more often qualifies false statements than true ones? Always doubt yourself whenever you find yourself saying something is obvious!*

Comment: @JaMiT Hmm, not sure what you mean. When I try to do it like that, regardless of whether the definition is inline or in a `.cpp` file, it points me to the purely virtual update method and gives me the error `'virtual void Base2::update' cannot be overloaded with 'void Base2::update'`

Comment: @JensB It works when I do it (and when Yksisarvinen did it), so *obviously* you did something wrong. *(Yes, obviously I am still intentionally over-using the word "obvious".)*

Comment: @JaMiT But Yksisarvinen never did it like that. Look at his answer again. He never overrode the update method and created a new update method in the same class. Frankly, I don't know how having two different methods with the same name and number of arguments could ever work.

Comment: @JensB What are you talking about? Yksisarvinen did keep the line you marked "Obviously not like this", as that line is the way to do it (changing `virtual` to `override` is merely cosmetic for current purposes). Yksisarvinen did change the inline definition to an out-of-class definition, as the inline definition is the problem. Exactly as I wrote. (Note: the answer was posted before my comment, which is why I did not post an answer. Yksisarvinen did not copy me.)

Comment: @JensB I don't know where you got this idea that there is supposed to be a new update method. I wrote nothing about "override" or "new" -- do a "find in page" to check that. You're apparently (excuse me, *obviously*) reading things that are not there.

Comment: @JaMiT Oh, now I see it. My bad. Apologies if I came off as arrogant, I was just genuinely trying to understand what you meant. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You *can* provide a definition for a pure virtual function, just not inline.

```
class Base2 : public Base
{
public:
    void update() override = 0;
};

void Base2::update() // Base2 is abstract regardless of this
{
    if(bSomeCondition)
    {
        update(); 
    }
}
```

However, this is not useful with the current implementation of `Base2::update`. Because a child class must override it anyway, `Base2` version will not be called unless used explicitly:

```
class Child: public Base2
{
public:
    void update() override
    {
        Base2::update(); //infinite recursion with such implementation
    }
};

// the other way would be to require calling it explicitly at call site

std::unique_ptr<Base2> ptr = std::make_unique<Child>();
ptr->Base2::update();
```

---

What you should do is to provide an implementation and another pure virtual function (possibly `protected`) to be called:

```
class Base2 : public Base
{
public:
    void update() override;

protected:
    virtual void doStuff() = 0;
};

void Base2::update()
{
    if(bSomeCondition)
    {
        doStuff(); //Calls child's update method
    }
}
```

Comment: A child class calling `Base2::update()` (and not `update()`) would not lead to any recursion.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Won't it go like: `Child::update()` calls `Base2::update()`, which in turn calls unqualified `update()`, which gets resolved to `Child::update()`, which again calls `Base2::update()`? I think I should illustrate it with code why it's a bad idea maybe.

Comment: Only because you chose to make an unqualified call in your intermediate pure virtual function. It's not intrinsic to the mechanism though - you could just have logged "don't call this". Admittedly I can't think of a _use_ unless you're trying to avoid crashing when making virtual function calls during destruction.

Comment: Ah, the OP's example at a desperate attempt. Yes, that would be infinite. But it reads like a more general problem in your answer. Different functions are indeed the path forward.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible and in my opinion it would be very illegible.

Comment: *"Not possible"* - demonstrably false.