# In a multi-level inheritance, does a grandchild require to implement a pure virtual method, if its parent has already implemented it?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions

```
class A {
  public:  virtual void start() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
  public: void start();
};

class Ba : public B {    
};
```

Do we need to redefine `start()` in `Ba` or the parent's `B::start()` would be enough?

Comment: It'll be enough. You may want to learn about `override` and `final` keywords.

Comment: It's surprising that I couldn't find any question of this kind to be linked as a duplicate after lot of searching!! Here is one related question, which asks something opposite: [Force all classes to implement / override a 'pure virtual' method in multi-level inheritance hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477581/force-all-classes-to-implement-override-a-pure-virtual-method-in-multi-level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parent's `start()` is enough.

You should though use the override keyword for B's reimplementation :

```
class B : public A {
  public: void start() override;
};
```

It makes it clear that the method is an implementation of a virtual one and the compiler will enforce that it will always be the case, even with future changes on class A.

Comment: as you said: 'it clear that the method is an implementation of a virtual one' so, what if instead of that I place virtual keyword in front of the method declaration B::start what difference would it make as it was in the case of override keyword?

Comment: @M.AbdulRehman the difference is, that in case the declaration of `virtual void start()` changes (e.g. to `virtual void start(int i)`) you end up having two virtual methods. That's what Mickaël meant with "even with future changes on class A". That said, if you want to override use `override`, if you want to make something virtual use `virtual`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all ur statement : public: void start(); will be problematic as it is must to override the pure virtual function in derived class otherwise derived class also becomes abstract.

Coming to your actual question B's start would be enough.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).